My model in database using SQLAlchemy and Flask cannot save data. TypeError: personal_guide() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content'
I am getting the response from a LLM called Moondream from Ollama. And there is nothing wrong with it because I tried to debug by print out its response, and it was fine. I believe that the problem lies in the database. I have two models in my database, one is "users" and the other is "personal_guide". The "users" works fine with authentication (log in, sign up) but the personal_guide just cannot. It always gets unexpected keyword argument.
Here is the error:
image from traceback
Here is my models.py:
class users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    personal_guide = db.relationship('personal_guide')
    def __init__(self, email, name, password):
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.password = password

class personal_guide(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    def __init__(self, content, user_id):
        self.content = content
        self.user_id = user_id


Here is my views.py (I use the Blueprint - auth and views instead of app):
@views.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def homepage():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_input = request.form.get('user_input') 
        response = str(moondream(user_input))
        print(response) #for debugging purpose
        print(current_user.id) #for debugging purpose
        try:
            user_info = personal_guide(content=response, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(user_info)
            db.session.commit()
            ai = personal_guide.query.filter_by(content=response).first()
            print(f"Retrieved guide content: {ai.content}, for user_id: {ai.user_id}") #for debugging purpose
            flash("Content saved", category='success')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            flash("Error saving content", category='failure')

        return render_template('homepage.html', response=ai.content)
    return render_template('homepage.html', current_user=current_user)

I check word for word, and try to print out response and user_id, all seem to work correctly. I cannot understand what is the problem.
And the result is that it never save the response to the model's content. Please help me! I would really appreciate that! Thanks a lot.

Please [edit] the question to include the complete error traceback (if necessary, remove the tryr/except so that the traceback is output).

Thank you for looking at my question! I've just upload the image of the error traceback. Could you take a look at it. Thanks a lot.

There seems to be a mismatch between the model definition and object in the route. How is it imported?  What does print(personnel_guide) output (in the route function)?

here are what I import in the views.py to use the database:
from website.ollama_test import moondream    from .models import users, personal_guide    from . import db  
And personal_guide takes the response of the AI, and insert it into content of that user_id.
